# stop/start servicios remotos del servidor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, servicio

Estoy intentando ver un servicio del servidor remoto desde un cliente.
Tengo el siguiente codigo pero me dice da un error: el servidor rpc no está disponible

```
try
        {
            string serviceName = "DHCP Client";
            string IP = "0.0.0.0"; // remote IP  
            string username = "na\\admin"; // remote username 
            string password = "123"; // remote password 
            ConnectionOptions connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            connectoptions.Username = username;
            connectoptions.Password = password;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\0.0.0.0.dominio.com\\root\\machine name");
            scope.Options = connectoptions;
            //WMI query to be executed on the remote machine  
            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Service where name = '" + serviceName + "'");
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();//aqui sale el error
                foreach (ManagementObject service in collection.OfType<ManagementObject>())
                {
                    if (service["started"].Equals(true))
                    {
                        //Start the service  
                        service.InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
                        serviceStop = "Start";
                        servicenamed = serviceName;
                        serviceStatus = "Stopped";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Stop the service  
                        service.InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
                        serviceStop = "Stop";
                        servicenamed = serviceName;
                        serviceStatus = "Running";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Edité la respuesta con más ideas para validar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría [`isConnected`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementscope.isconnected?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Management_ManagementScope_IsConnected) para validar el estado del ManagementScope.

Lo otro, ese error se va a dar cuando el puerto para RPC esté bloqueado por el firewall o el servicio esté detenido.

Valida en el firewall del servidor que el servicio permite conexiones entrantes (Firewall --> Allowed apps).

[image: Firewall config]

Lo otro, valida que el servicio esté corriendo (Ejecuta `services.msc`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparte de estas validaciones, es importante revisar antivirus en el servidor al que quieres conectarte (pues es un puerto comúnmente susceptible a ataques históricamente) y si hay algún equipo de seguridad entre tu terminal y el servidor (un WAF o IPF va a bloquear peticiones por puertos no permitidos y este está entre los puertos que normalmente se bloquean)

Comment: puse validar el ManagementScope usando un if isconnected y me lo regresa en false

Comment: @Manny pues eso, no conecta y puede ser por lo que te indico en la respuesta

Comment: el firewall esta desactivado y el servicio actualmente esta corriendo, checare lo de los puertos ya que actualmente instalaron un nuevo firewall para separa vlan y otras cosas